# Flutter StreamProvider<List<DogModel>> can't be assigned

Tags: firebase, flutter, provider

I'm getting the following error `The argument type 'StreamProvider<List<DogModel>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<List<DogModel>>?'`

Happing when I try to set the stream `stream: stream,`

Here the stream in the widget state

```
final stream = StreamProvider<List<DogModel>>(
create: (context) =>
    DogFirestoreService().getDogs('GeVnAbdq9BWs1STbytlAU65qkbc2'),
initialData: const [],
```

);

And the widget build

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//final test = context.watch<List<DogModel>>();
//print(test);
return SizedBox(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: StreamBuilder<List<DogModel>>(
    stream: stream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return const Text('no data');
      }

      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        return const Text('error');
      }

      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        return SizedBox(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 65.0,
                  left: 18.0,
                  right: 18.0,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  dogsCount(value.dogsList.length),
                  style: AppStyles.listsHeaderTextStyle,
                ),
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 5,
                  bottom: 20,
                  left: 15,
                  right: 15,
                ),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemCount: value.dogsList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => DogProfileCardWidget(
                  dogInfo: value.dogsList[index],
                  editProfile: openProfileScreen,
                  dogIndex: index,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
      return const Text('data');
    },
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the `stream` variable is a `StreamProvider`.

`StreamProvider`s are not `Stream`s, they are `Widget`s. So `StreamBuilder` does not understand what it is.

Instead you may want to do:

```dart
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  const Example({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> {
  // The stream needs to be stored in a StatefulWidfet
  // as you shouldn't create a new stream when the widget rebuild
  final stream = DogFirestoreService().getDogs('GeVnAbdq9BWs1STbytlAU65qkbc2');

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<List<Dog>>(
      stream: stream,
      builder: ...,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: should you have your Stream in the root view multi providers like so 

StreamProvider<List<DogModel>>(
          create: (context) =>
              DogFirestoreService().getDogs('GeVnAbdq9BWs1STbytlAU65qkbc2'),
          initialData: const [],
          child: const DogsListScreen(),
        ),

Or inside the widget ?

Comment: Both are fine. Whether you use `Streamprovider` + `context.watch` or `StreamBuilder` is a matter of choice here.

Comment: Thanks, @Remi shouldn't  getdogs() be abstracted inside the provider file and not the service file was looking for docs on but didn't see anything

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `StreamBuilder` since you're using `StreamProvider`. Also, it's not obvious on your code where are you placing the `StreamProvider`. It's a widget by the way so it should be on the widget tree above the one shown on your example. I see you're assigning it to `final stream = ...` but I'm not sure why because it does not return a stream.

`StreamProvider` will subscribe to the stream you gave (i.e., `DogFirestoreService().getDogs('...')`) and once the data arrives, it'll provide it to you down the tree (initially, it'll provide the `initialData`).

I made a simple example on DartPad that you can view here:
[Stream Provider Example](https://dartpad.dev/?id=d864144bf77c5217f7a00fa27e96de2a).

Once you place the `StreamProvider` widget above the widget of interest, then in your `build` method you can access the data directly like this:

```dart
final data = context.watch<List<DogModel>>();
```

In the first build, you'll get the `initialData` you gave to `StreamProvider` which is an empty list. So you can do:

```dart
@override 
build(BuildContext context) {
  final data = context.watch<List<DogModel>>();
  if (data.isEmpty) {
     return const Text('no data');
  } 
  
  return SizedBox(/* the rest of your code */);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I need it inside the StreamBuilder which than has a list view builder

Comment: if do the data and add it to the stream I get The argument type 'List<DogModel>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<List<DogModel>>?'